# session attribute null in my spring interceptor

Tags: spring, session, controller

I am having trouble with getting a value that I had put into a session.
I want to check this value with an interceptor but I only get a null.

This is where I put the variable "trustedUser"

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/context/{token}", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<ContexteUI> getContextByToken(@PathVariable("token") String token, HttpSession session)
        throws ContextFault_Exception {

    HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;
    if (validation(token)){
        session.setAttribute("trustedUser","trustedUser");
    } else {
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<ContexteUI>(contexte, httpStatus);
}
```

This is my interceptor:

```
 public class AuthentificationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

       System.out.println("Pre-handle");

       String trustedUserTest = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("trustedUser");
       System.out.println("trustedUserTest: "+ trustedUserTest); // I only get null here, why ?

       return true;

    }
}
```

Where did I get wrong ?

Comment: Did you try it getContextByToken(@PathVariable("token") String token, HttpServletRequest request)  {HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("trustedUser", trustedUser);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry the problem was due to another cause:
I had deplued the jsp page with grunt on the 8000 port
and my API(services) was displayed on the 8080 port.

Apparently the browser could not make a link between the two.

So I moved all on the 8080 port and it works now

Answer (score 1):

A [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) gets called before the appropriate HandlerAdapter triggers the execution of the handler itself. Those said, you are trying to access the attribute from session in `preHandle()` phase, which is called before the handler execution itslef and you haven't set the attribute into session yet.

So either you can move your logic to `postHandle()` phase and get session attribute there, or change your logic if you really need something to do in `preHandle`phase.

And `postHandle()` is called after the handler execution (that is why , it allows to manipulate the ModelAndView object before rendering it to the view page)

Comment: Thanks for the effort but the problem was elsewehre (non trivial)